# Message build error doesn't appear in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

By mistake I click on "don't show this dialog again" for this message that appear when start the program, so now I can't see the error.

How can I return the appearance of this message?

[image]

Comment: What are the errors that's preventing you from building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please enter the following settings:

Tools=>Options=>Projects and Solutions=>Build and Run

In On Run, when build or deployment errors occur, change the drop-down box to Prompt to launch

[image]

After that, if there is a problem with your project, a dialog box will pop up

[image]